# What is the php code to display a field of a referenced node in the node form of the node that references the node?

Tags: entities, display-suite

So I have a node (content type A) with some text fields and a reference field referencing another node (content type B).

When a user wants to update one of the text fields an existing node (content type A) , they need to see the text field of the referenced node (content type B).

Question: what is the php code that I can use to output that textfield from the referenced node (content type B) on the node form of the referencing node (content type A).

I'd like to add this to a code field in Display Suite and I also like to learn how to retrieve the variables from a loaded node and how to display them.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use panels, I highly suggest this method. It might be complicated at first but no coding is required.

- Enable the built in panels page for the path `node/%node/edit`.
- Add a selection rule: node (from node being edited) is of bunle 'type A'
- in **context** configuration page of enabled panel variant, create a relation using the entity reference field you have other.
- in Panels content add each field of node being edited (and submit buttons too!).

  - or perhaps add the general form instead of each field individually.
- again in add content, node section, choose rendered entity.

  - or create a view with a display of type `content pane` (ctools `views content panes` has to be enabled). Add a contextual filter of type nid, choose `argument input: nid from context` in view's configuration and use it to render the entity in panel. while adding this view to panel, choose the node you added with relationship.

Any way, the original question:
First, implement hook_field_extra_fields. take node module's node_field_extra_field as an example. or follow this question: [how should I use hook_field_extra_fields()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10527/how-should-i-use-hook-field-extra-fields)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_extra_fields().
 */
function MODULE_field_extra_fields() {
   $etype = 'node';
   $bundle = 'content_type_a';
   $field_name = 'the_other_entity';
   $extra[$etype][$bundle]['form'][$field_name] = array(
     'label' => t('The other entity'),
    'description' => t('Renders the related entity'),
    'weight' => 0,
  );
  return $extra;
}
```

Next, taking node.module as an example, implement a form alter for your content type:

```
function MODULE_node_form_content_type_a_form_alter(&$f, &$fs) {
  $field_name = 'the_other_entity';
  $f[$field_name] = array(
    '#markup' => $the_mighty_markup,
  );
}
```

Here is another example how to do it: http://johnheaven.eu/en/extending-drupals-user-contact-form it attachs fields to contact form though.

And about the $the_mighty_markup, here you have to generate output of your entity. One suggested way is to create a view, add a contextual filter on nid to it, display the fields you want. Then in your code execute the view to generate the output:

```
$this_node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $this_node);
$other_node = $this_node->field_the_other_node_er->value();
$nid = $other_node->nid; 
// or simply: 
$nid = $this_node->field_the_other_node_er->nid->value();  
$the_mighty_markup = views_embed_view('the_created_view_of_yours', 'master', $nid);
```

edit:
This is how to output a view: http://codekarate.com/blog/outputting-drupal-7-view-programmatically-contextual-filters-arguments

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I thought it was simply a few lines of code that would go into the DS code field though. I'll take a look at your first suggestion of implementing Panels and see how that goes. I'll surely come back to this topic because it's a lot of information for me right now.

Comment: Oh! I think i missed it... it is a few line of codes which goes into ds! Use the last snippet and print the markup in ds code;  i haven't worked with ds custom field but it should work.